# ember.js RESTAdapter: prevent caching in IE9

Tags: ajax, rest, internet-explorer, ember.js

My ember cli app uses the RESTAdapter. In IE9 the ajax call is reused from cache, so data changes are not reflected. Chrome etc. always does a proper call to the server.

I know this is a common issue with IE9. In other apps (not ember) I just added  ?_=timestamp to the ajax calls.

How can I do something similar in ember cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `buildURL` method for your adapter.

app/adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
    const now = Date.now();

    if (query === undefined) {
        return this._super(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) + '?_' + now;
    }

    query._ = now;

    return this._super(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query);
  }
});
```

It will result in:

```
this.store.findAll('thing');
// REQUEST http://api.com/things?_1441892715766

this.store.query('thing', { something: true });
// REQUEST http://api.com/things?_=1441892783338&something=true
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/88588c442c974f30c006)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/88588c442c974f30c006)

Answer (score 1):

In my Application controller in the init-function, I added:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
```

This will do the trick.